# How to make buttons at the bottom of the screen to perisist even after scrolling in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a listview on the screen and on the bottom of the page i have 4 buttons.I want the four buttons to persist at the bottom of the screen even after scrolling the listview.I am new to android, should i use fragments or is there any other way to do it.Also can anyone give a link to a good fragments tutorial.Please help!!

Comment: Could we see your xml? (Or java code if you're generating your layout that way) But my first though would be that you have your buttons within the list view, if you put them outside the list view they won't scroll

Comment: I have not started developing yet.I wanted the ideas to start the development.

Comment: Make a persistent footer (it could be some buttons or a LinearLayout including them) anchored to the ParentBottom of your RelativeLayout container. Then put the ListView **above** it. DONE! Forgot to mention: **forget using setFooterView**

Comment: Stack overflow is really to help after you've implemented something and had a problem with it. You shouldn't need fragments to achieve this though

Answer (score 1):

You could use a RelativeLayout to set a listView fullfilling the entire screen. Then, below of the listView define other relative to be the container of your buttons. Since this container is defined below your listView in the xml it will be setled "over" your listView

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_playlist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >

    <!-- PUT YOUR BUTTONS HERE -->
   </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to make an own "area" for the buttons besides the listview. Like that (just pseudocode!)

```
<page>
  <listview>...</listview>
  <buttonarea>
    <button>...</button>
    ...
  </buttonarea>
</page>
```

Comment: it is pseudo-code, like I explained. He just wanted to know how to align the list-view and the buttons so that the buttons stay where they are. And that's what my pseudo-code explains. I thought he can figure out himself, that he can order the buttons in a LinearLayout.

Comment: Well, these tags are more similar to HTML than to Android XML. If you used terms like layout instead of page, container instead of buttonarea it would be more similar to Android pseudo-code.

Comment: To explain the idea of placing a group of buttons BESIDES a list it is absolutely sufficient in my opinion. It is even platform-independent, so that if someone else comes by this question and wants to do the same on a webpage or on a java-desktop-program he can use that explanation, too.

Comment: This question in **Android specific**, not **platform independent**.

Comment: sorry, if I wrote something that isn't sufficient for your quality-requirements. I just wanted to help him. And I thought my answer is more helpful, than giving him the whole code ready for copy and paste. I totally know how to write Android-Code, I wrote two Apps myself.

Comment: Don't feel sorry. Here is a place where to ask and answer **specific** question. Possibly, answers (no matter if long or short) should be quality answers. Yours is not of bad quality. It just can be bettered